IMAT 2024 question about a moving pendulum seems to be wrong
Here is the question from IMAT 2024:

A pendulum rod moves from the vertical position. Which of the
following statements is false?
A) In the absence of friction, the
pendulum tends to come to a stop after a certain time
B) In the
absence of friction, the motion is simple harmonic oscillation.
C) In the presence of friction oscillatory motion is damped.
D) The pendulum stops after reaching a certain height and then swings back.
E) The
pendulum describes a circular arc during its motion.

The correct answer is A (according to IMAT), but I strongly believe that B, D and even E are false too.
B is false because the motion of a pendulum is approximated to be a simple harmonic oscillation only for small angles (when theta is less than 6 degrees).  This comes from the differential equation
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{l}\sin(\theta) = 0$$
Which simplifies to $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{l}\theta = 0$ only when $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ for small angles.
D is also false because if the initial energy of the pendulum overcomes its gravitational energy, the pendulum should rotate in a circular motion indefinitely.
Even if we think the person who has written this test has assumed that $\theta$ is small, then E would be wrong as well. Because when $\theta$ is small, we consider the movement of the pendulum only on the x-axis to approximate it as a simple harmonic motion. In that case, we can't really say it's describing a circular arc if we are viewing it as a simple harmonic motion in one dimension, right?
Is my reasoning about the problem correct? Because if so, the question has more than one correct answer.

B is false and D depends on what the question means by "vertical position". Anyway the correct option is opinion-based.

But in any case your reasoning is valid.

I wasn't even clear about the meaning of the first sentence ("A pendulum moves from the vertical position."). Why does it move? Is it swinging under gravity or is another force being applied to move it?

@PhilipWood Indeed. That's very confusing. If it's another force being applied to it, then it can very well make it rotate indefinitely in the absence of friction.

"How is my question opinion-based?" Because it depends on the usage of the English language and also the intention of the question setter (who clearly did not set the question in a clear unambiguous manner). The only way is to ask the people who set the question.

@VincentThacker That's the whole point of my question! To know if the question, as stated by the IMAT, is valid or it should be removed from the exam.

@math.n00b "is valid or it should be removed from the exam" This debate isn't really something that is on topic here. This site is primarily a place to ask conceptual questions. And on that front, it seems that you are already clear about the physics concepts involved. This post should be addressed to whoever regulates the exam...

@VincentThacker:  But the OP didn't ask whether the question should be removed from the exam (at least not in the original version.) It just asked whether the answer as given was correct, which is a question about physics.  And I confined my attention to this point in the answer I gave.

@VincentThacker I understand that. But I want to post the question here and ask others to verify my understanding to have a stronger case when I bring it to their attention. :) And as far as I know, that is not against the rules of stackexchange.

@math.n00b I think your question can be reworded to be on topic if you simply ask whether your conceptual reasoning is correct (i.e. remove the part about "Or is the question wrong?", because that is opinion-based).

I would agree with you that the question is imprecisely stated.  Specifically, the question as stated implicitly assumes that the angle of oscillation is small.  If that assumption is made, B is true to a very good approximation, D is definitely true, and A is the only false statement.

Do you think my objection is legit though? Because it had multiple correct answers (false statements), I refused to answer this test and I lost 1.5 points.

@math.n00b: As far as your lost points go, what I think doesn't really matter; what matters is what the MIUR thinks. You'll have to take it up with them.

Choice A isn't absolutely false either.  When the pendulum reaches an extremum and reverses, it has speed = 0.  Thus it is instantaneously "stopped" after "a certain time".  A little bit of a stretch, maybe, but certainly an arguable point, especially considering that exam questions ought to be clear and unambiguous.

Even if we assume that the angle of oscillation is small, then E can be wrong too. I mean if we view the movement as simple harmonic motion, then we are really viewing it as a one-dimensional motion on the x-axis instead of a circular arc.
